# Building NFT Marketplace on Tezos, getting unknown error

Tags: blockchain, nft

( first of all: sorry for my bad english )
I'm trying to build NFT Marketplace on Tezos blockchain from https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/create-an-nft-marketplace-on-tezos , This is my first work with blockchain field and i don't really understand what's going on, i followed the tutorial fully and i was getting some react errors that i fixed, but now I'm stuck with unknown error while i was trying to mint/create NFT on this project... I completed this form:
[NFT Marketplace create page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxwGN.png)
and when i clicked the mint button, the temple request pop up and shows the warning that the transaction will likely to fail with this error detail:

```
{
  "error": [
    {
      "errorDetail": {},
      "name": "HttpRequestFailed",
      "isError": true
    },
    {
      "errorDetail": {},
      "name": "HttpRequestFailed",
      "isError": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I really don't understand where is the problem and I'm noob in this field and I need serious help, I will be thankful if anyone could help me with this or share tutorial on how to make NFT Marketplace on Tezos to guide me in this field.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that you are following the documented steps in order.And look for errors that are reported when making http requests, i.e. there are some wrong requests in your code, you can add some log printing to the place where the request is called